# Grouping column values into a single value in Sql

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a sql statement statement where i filter my data by certain values but also i want to further filter or group where i check the value.

My data includes results like Elementary, Collage, University, Home School, Students, School Students, Home Students, Senior Students, Preschool, PhD Candidates, Candidates.

Currently, I want to create a SQL statement where I return rows that contain:  Elementry, Collage, University. I also want to return Students but also include Candatates as Students.

This is what i have so far:

```
SELECT 
   MAX(CASE
       WHEN x.type = 'education' THEN
         CASE
           WHEN y.name like '%Elementry%' THEN y.name
           WHEN y.name like '%Collage%' THEN y.name
           WHEN y.name like '%University%' THEN y.name
           WHEN y.name like '%Students%' THEN y.name
           WHEN y.name like '%Candidates%' THEN
             //HERE i need to merge Candidates as Students
             SET y.name = 'Students' // can i try something like this?
         END
     END)
```

Comment: Please Edit your question and include an example se of rows from the tab, and an example of the output you want.

Comment: Are you saying that, when `y.name` is like `%Candidates%`, you want to return a value of of `Students` instead of `y.name`? You could simply use `WHEN y.name like '%Candidates%' THEN 'Students'`